# Can't initialize array of not copyable structs

Tags: arrays, rust

I have an array of not copyable structs `[notCopyableStruct; 10]`, which I want to later initialize in a for loop like this:

```rs
let mut arr: [notCopyableStruct; 10];
for i in 0..10 {
    arr[i] = /* sth. */;
}
```

But Rust won't let me modify an uninitialized array.

I tried using Options since they are made exactly for that, but that doesn't work either since `None` is an `Option<notCopyableStruct>` type and it can only be copied if `notCopyableStruct` itself can be copied

```rs
let mut arr: [Option<notCopyableStruct>; 10] = [None; 10];
for i in 0..10 {
    arr[i] = Some(/* sth. */);
}
```

I don't want to use a vector since it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: Do you need an array? Would a `Vec` suffice? Could you `try_into` the array?

Comment: @tadman No, I need an array